# Cakephp 2.0: Change select item text with FormHelper without modifying ID

Tags: cakephp, formhelper

I'm sure this is simple but I can't figure out how to achieve it:

I have a model with a `title` and `sub_title` column; there are frequently entries that have the same `title` and are differentiable only by their `sub_title`. So, I need the views for CRUD commands to display effectively this:

```
<option>Title: Subtitle</option>
```

But I don't know how to get FormHelper to do this. Can someone provide a strategy to a generic form of this (ie. :

```
echo $this->Form->input('title', array(
                                        //whatever option(s) solve this 
                                       ));
```

Solutions or advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: you mean `$this->Form->...` I guess

Comment: Yeah, I did, whoops. I think the question stands, tho. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your options differently, something using the [`Set`](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/set) class:

```
$results = $this->Model->find('all');
$options = Set::combine($results, '{n}.Model.id', array('{0}: {1}', '{n}.Model.title', '{n}.Model.sub_title'));
```

So your option array would look something like

```
array(
  0 => 'Title: sub title',
  1 => 'Title: different sub'
);
```

And set your dropdown to use those options

```
$this->Form->input('title', array('options' => $options));
```

Comment: Perfect. _Exactly_ what I was seeking. A million thanks. I'm not familiar with the {n} syntax—any chance  you've got a link to where in the API I could read about this? Or is this something to do with PHP as a language?

Comment: Cool! It's Cake specific. I added a link to the `Set` class api docs. There are links to the book within those docs with examples and such.